# running shell scripts in parallel from the host script

Tags: shell, unix

I have made a shell script which greps some logs and puts the output in one text file. Basically this script is run on 10 other servers and the output text file is copied to the host server via `scp`. Now from the host server I need to invoke all the scripts at one go so that I get all the 10 log files in minimum time (almost parallel). The scripts on each server take around 10 secs to complete.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at [GNU parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/). [`ClusterSSH`](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/clusterssh/index.php?title=Main_Page) and [`pconsole`](http://www.heiho.net/pconsole/) may also be useful, as mentioned [here](https://serverfault.com/q/2533/60384).

If you insist on creating your own tool, [this tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/execute-commands-on-multiple-linux-or-unix-servers.html) might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

The possible solution is to create subprocess on the host server which will basically try to ssh the servers and on the server side, you can put the commands to run shell script in ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bashrc which will basically run on log in. You can also pipeline the commands after ssh. If you are facing issue with fingerprint confirmation, you can add your host key to authorized keys in servers .ssh folder. It should be done easily.
 *and you can initiate subprocess in parallel

Answer (score 0):

To start the logging almost at the same time, send the processes to the background:

```
host_urls=( url1 ... url10 )
for u in ${host_urls[@]}; do
  ssh ... $u your_server_logging_script &
done
```

That will incur delays much smaller than any network glitching could, so it's the best you can do without actually synchronising time on the servers or writing extra code.

`your_server_logging_script` would of course contain the `grep` and `scp` calls to get the files back to the central server. Don't forget to name the files uniquely (host prefixed for example) or they would overwrite each other.

Answer (score 0):

You might use distributed shells like `pdsh` http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdsh/